# How to calculate mAP (mean average precision) for the whole dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, average-precision

I am new to computer vision and I have a simple question that could not get any answer for on the web. I am using mask rcnn implementation by Matterport to perform a binary classification on some images and I have some extra lines of code that compute the mAP for each image. Now I would like to know, if I can add up the mAPs calculated for each image and then divide the number to get mAP for the whole dataset, and if not, how can I compute the overall mAP? (preferrably using the utilities of the mask rcnn model)

Comment: 2 steps  - 
1. For each image calculate the average precision across different recall threshold points -  Mathematically, we say it as - Integral of the "Area under the precision recall curve" for each image. 
2. Average of the above across total images i.e (sum of total precision) / (number of images)
Would be more clear if you could share the output format as a sample.

Comment: @Prachi  Thanks for the response. That is much more convenient than what I had in mind, but I don't understand why it works. Could you please elaborate on that, or introduce me to some text book? Because I thought that precision and recall should be calculated for all instances across all images and then the area under the curve would yield the final mAP, right?

Comment: What is instances here "instances across all images"?

Comment: @Prachi by instances I mean any object that is detected. So for example under this article (https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/map-mean-average-precision-for-object-detection-45c121a31173#:~:text=mAP%20(mean%20average%20precision)%20is,difference%20between%20AP%20and%20mAP.) imagine that we have the same number of objects, but divided into two images. Would the results be the same if I calculate mAP for each image and then average across all images, or add all detection results, rank them and then calculate mAP?

Comment: Okay, So in object detection the results are reported at image level along with the corresponding detected Bounding Box.
So,if an image has 5 Bboxes, it will have rows in the prediction dataset and precision-recall be calculated individually for each bbox.
Explanation here could help https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260430/average-precision-in-object-detection

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something like

```
np.sum(recall)/num_test
np.sum(precision)/num_test
```

where `num_test` is number of test images

Just keep training and test data separate.